# activity in past hour

Tags: php, date, time

I am trying to work out if users have had activity in the past hour. The following is my code, but it always returns yes, no matter what:

```
$houraway = (int)mktime() + (60 * 60);
$now = mktime();

while($user = mysql_fetch_array($qusers))   {
    echo $user['Name']." - ";
    $datetime = explode(" ", $user['Custom6']);
    $date = $datetime[0];
    $date = explode("-", $date);
    $time = $datetime[1];
    $time = explode(":", $time);
    $hr = $time[0];
    $min = $time[1];
    $sec = $time[2];
    $y = $date[0];
    $m = $date[1];
    $d = $date[2];
    $lastloginmk = (int)mktime($hr, $min, $sec, $m, $d, $y);
    echo " - ".$lastloginmk;
    if($lastloginmk <= $houraway) { echo "yes"; } else { echo "no"; }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

last activity time is stored in the database like this:

```
2009-09-22 13:32:28
```

Thanks in advance!

Ryan

Comment: **line #2 is irrelevant.

Comment: Why don't you print `$lastloginmk` and `$houraway`? Keep printing variables until you isolate where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
$houraway = (int)mktime() + (60 * 60);
```

is looking into the future by an hour. The last login will always be earlier than the future, because the last login must be in the past.

I think you would want last login to be *greater than* one hour *before* now.  Change the `$houraway` and change your last comparison, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code you want is:

```
$hourago = mktime() - (60 * 60);

while($user = mysql_fetch_array($qusers))   {
    echo $user['Name']." - ";
    $lastloginmk = strtotime($user['Custom6']);
    echo " - ".$lastloginmk;
    if($lastloginmk <= $hourago) { echo "yes"; } else { echo "no"; }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Hope this helps.